# Traefik started but my services are not using it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm using a VPS with Debian 10 on it. I also have one domain name.

My goal is to self-host a few services, like FreshRSS or Nextcloud. To deploy these services, I'm using Docker and Docker Compose. I have one folder per service.

Because I would like to get a reverse proxy and assign subdomains to services (for example : cloud.domainname.com to Nextcloud), I installed Traefik yesterday. However, I cannot get the service to work. This is probably bad configuration from me, as I'm a total beginner in setting up reverse proxies. For example, I'm trying to get it to work with ArchiveBox, which runs on the port 8000. I would like Traefik to map my subdomain archive.domainname.com to the port 8000 of my VPS.

These are the steps I did yesterday:

1. Installed [ArchiveBox](https://archivebox.io) on my VPS with Docker Compose and configured it. It's working successfully.
2. Created a new network for traefik: `sudo docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.0/16 traefik_lan`
3. Installed Traefik with Docker Compose, added dynamic configuration by following tutorials.
4. Added the labels and the network to the Docker Compose file of ArchiveBox.
5. Started both. However, ArchiveBox creates a new network and does not seems to use the Traefik one. I can also still access directly ArchiveBox at domainname.com:8000.

Below are the config files.

### ArchiveBox

---

#### ArchiveBox docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# Usage:
#     docker-compose up -d
#     docker-compose run archivebox init
#     echo "https://example.com" | docker-compose run archivebox archivebox add
#     docker-compose run archivebox add --depth=1 https://example.com/some/feed.rss
#     docker-compose run archivebox config --set PUBLIC_INDEX=True
# Documentation:
#     https://github.com/ArchiveBox/ArchiveBox/wiki/Docker#docker-compose

version: '3.7'

services:
    archivebox:
        # build: .
        image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE:-archivebox/archivebox:latest}
        command: server 0.0.0.0:8000
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        environment:
            - USE_COLOR=True
            - SHOW_PROGRESS=False
            - SEARCH_BACKEND_ENGINE=sonic
            - SEARCH_BACKEND_HOST_NAME=sonic
            - SEARCH_BACKEND_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data
        depends_on:
            - sonic
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_lan"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archiveboxnotls.rule=Host(`${ARCHIVE_URL}`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archiveboxnotls.entrypoints=webinsecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archiveboxnotls.middlewares=tlsredir@file"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archivebox.rule=Host(`${ARCHIVE_URL}`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archivebox.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archivebox.tls=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.archivebox.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
        networks:
          - traefik_lan
    # Run sonic search backend
    sonic:
        image: valeriansaliou/sonic:v1.3.0
        ports:
            - 1491:1491
        environment:
            - SEARCH_BACKEND_PASSWORD=SecretPassword
        volumes:
            - ./etc/sonic/config.cfg:/etc/sonic.cfg
            - ./data:/var/lib/sonic/store/

networks:
  traefik_lan:
    external: true
```

I'm then expected to run it like so:

`sudo ARCHIVE_URL=archive.mydomain.com docker-compose up -d`

### Traefik

---

This is the structure of my /traefik folder in /home.

```
.
├── config
│   ├── acme.json
│   ├── dynamic-conf
│   │   ├── dashboard.toml
│   │   ├── tlsredir.toml
│   │   └── tls.toml
│   └── traefik.toml
└── docker-compose.yml
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:v2.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - traefik_lan
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config:/etc/traefik:ro
      - ./config/acme.json:/acme.json
networks:
  traefik_lan:
    external: true
```

#### traefik.toml

```
[api]
  dashboard = true

[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    exposedByDefault = false

  [providers.file]
    directory = "/etc/traefik/dynamic-conf"
    watch = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

  [entryPoints.webinsecure]
    address = ":80"


  [entryPoints.dot]
    address = ":853"

[certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
  email = "myemail@gmail.com"
  caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
 #caServer: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
  storage = "acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlsChallenge]


[accessLog]
  format = "json"
  [accessLog.fields]
    defaultMode = "drop"
    [accessLog.fields.names]
      "ClientAddr" = "keep"
      "RequestAddr" = "keep"
      "RequestMethod" = "keep"
      "RequestPath" = "keep"
      "DownstreamStatus" = "keep"
```

#### dashboard.toml

```
[http.routers.api]
  rule = "Host(`traefik.domain.tld`)"
  entrypoints = ["webinsecure"]
  service = "api@internal"
  middlewares = ["tlsredir@file"]

[http.routers.api-secure]
  rule = "Host(`traefik.domain.tld`)"
  entrypoints = ["websecure"]
  service = "api@internal"
  middlewares = ["secured"]
  [http.routers.api-secure.tls]
    certResolver = "letsencrypt"
```

#### tlsredir.toml

```
[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.tlsredir.redirectScheme]
    scheme = "https"
    permanent = true
```

#### tls.toml

```
[tls]
  [tls.options]
    [tls.options.default]
      minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
      sniStrict = true
      cipherSuites = [
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
      ]
      curvePreferences = ["CurveP521","CurveP384"]
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Comment: You missed the part where you explain how traefik doesn't work - comprising the story about what happens when you open the traeffik port in a browser. You also forgot to tell traefik which port your service is listening on, since this has nothing to do with the `ports:` docker compose clause.

Comment: If I go to domainname.com, I get something like "Browser could not connect to the server...". If I go to domainname.com:8000, then I can access ArchiveBox. I would like to  have archive.domainname.com to get access to ArchiveBox, with a SSL certificate.

Comment: Should I add [entryPoints.webinsecure] address = ":8000" in traefik.toml?

Comment: You should remove the `ports: 8000:8000` entry on the archivebox container, since ingress will be handled by traefik, there's no need to expose 8000 directly to the internet. Also I don't think this will work `sudo ARCHIVE_URL=... docker-compose up ...`, archivebox doens't check that env var, you have to use the `docker-compose run archivebox add https://example.com` command to add URLs.

Comment: Hi Nick. I switched to Caddy, my setup is now working, but I would still like to fix it with Traefik. You're right, I now use expose instead of ports for ArchiveBox. The command you mention was to pass to Traefik, not to run the actual scrapping of websites. What I think I'm missing here is the part where I tell Traefik to listen on a subdomain and redirect to ArchiveBox.